# Write Bash script to download a variable number of .gitignore files based on number of arguments in command?

Tags: bash, gitignore

How can I write `gitignore Python` at the commandline and have it run

> `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore > ./.gitignore`

and have `gitignore Python macOS` do

> `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/macOS.gitignore > ./.gitignore`

The number of arguments after `gitignore` would be variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Go to the bottom

It sounds like you want to write a bash function to loop over the arguments and write the output to .gitignore. There are three concepts to go through here: loop iteration, variable expansion, and stdout redirection.

Firstly, you need a function body, which is created with `funcname() { ...; }` (the `;` is optional if you break the end bracket into its own line).

Second, you need to iterate over parameters passed to this function. `$@` is a special variable in bash that is set to all unshifted parameters in the given script/function. To loop over this, you can use the for loop construct: `for i in "${@}"`. Curly brackets around `@` are optional, but quotes are required since you don't want to expand `funcname "a" "b c"` to evaluate to three loop iterations. To learn more, look up IFS splitting.

Third, you want to expand your new variable `i` in the middle of a url. Make sure it's double quoted:

```
for i in "${@}"; do
  curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/${i}.gitignore"
done
```

Finally, you want to write all this out to a file `.gitignore`. It might sound intuitive to just add `>.gitignore` at the end of your curl command, but in reality, you want to put it after `done`. This is because an invocation like `funcname Python macOS` will run:

```
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Python.gitignore" >.gitignore
curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/macOS.gitignore" >.gitignore
```

The `>` redirection operator will overwrite gitignore with python's contents, then overwrite it again with macOS's contents. You really want to capture the stdout of both commands and overwrite .gitignore with their contents (alternatively you could do the above with `>>`, but running your command multiple times will cause duplicate lines in your .gitignore).

So your final function will be:

```
gitignore() {
  for i in "${@}"; do
    curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/${i}.gitignore"
  done >.gitignore
}
```